# Require login every time user returns to Android application

Tags: android, security

I am working on an Android app that deals with sensitive user information.  One of the requirements is that the user is required to log back into the application whenever they leave it and come back.  This is easily dealt with for the case when the user presses the Home button and then relaunches the app (`android:clearTaskOnLaunch` attribute on the `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`).  However, we need to do the same thing when the user long presses the Home button, switches to another application, then comes back.

I have researched this every way that I can think of and have not found a workable solution.  Is this even possible with Android?

When answering, please keep in mind that this is a business requirement which I have no control over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I had the same problem yesterday. This is what I did and it works fine:

1. Added `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the main activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. Called my boss and say: ey, this is going to take a long while... hold on!
3. Went and drank beer all night.

Just to clarify, my main activity only has a button that says login and launches the login page.

Comment: Adding both `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and `android:clearTaskOnLauch="true"` to the LoginActivity seems to do exactly what I am looking for.  Are there any other side effects to using a specialized launch mode like this?

Comment: No... just take a look at the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode

Comment: BTW, I suggest this way instead of using the lyfecycle methods since sometimes you will see that the application is rendered and then you will see the login stuff. That's not good, at least for this kind of applications. In my case, for instance, I can't allow others to see the list of bank accounts for a second before prompt to login.

Comment: i feel like this should be the one answer for all quick-fix coding problems where you want the day off.......

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? You can always clear whatever session you are saving in the proper [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) method.

Comment: Our application has many Activities which the user can launch, making the stack potentially several layers deep.  I want a solution that would be applied to every Activity launched after login.  Having a base class would be a natural way to leverage the lifecycle, but (unless I am missing something) wouldn't that start to cause the user to get logged out just by moving deeper into the application as other Activities further down the stack get stopped or paused?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly that you want to require an authorisation every time someone backs into the app, whether afresh or coming back to it, then you can override the onRestart() activity lifecycle event on the activity (or activities). So in onRestart() you can redirect the user to the login screen (you may also wish to consider onResume() depending on your requirements)

The lifecycle chart on this page will make this clearer:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: The challenge with this approach is distinguishing when the user returned to an Activity from another Activity within the same app, vs from a different app.

Comment: OK, so how about whenever you start a new activity within your own app you always pass in a bundle parameter to signify that the user is logged in. Then if that parameter is not provided, you know the activity started from outside of your app (either a fresh start, or a restart) so you require authentication.

Comment: I don't think passing in a bundle parameter will do us any good because the bundle is saved out when the activity is saved out and the same parameters come back through when the activity starts back up.

Answer (score -1):

Would it be possible to make it a time based thing, rather than strictly left the app and returned?

You could have a separate service that keeps track of when the last time the user accessed the application was.

I.e, in each onPause the Activity tells the service that an Activity was paused.  The service records the time of that.

In each onResume, the Activity informs the Service that it wishes to resume.  If some amount of time has passed since the last onPause, then the Service indicates that a login is required.

I think this would make a nicer user experience than just every time they leave the app.  That could be very frustrating, to take 30 seconds to read a text, and then have to sign in again.

I suppose if you tweak it to have the timeout be very short, it has very similar behavior to what you requested anyways, but with the option of making it less draconion.

Comment: I agree that this could make for a very frustrating user experience, but it is not my call to make.  I think this idea has some potential if I am able to change the minds of the business, which is unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way to implement this, would be to add a field to your main activity like `private boolean isLocked = true;`.

To lock the app when another one is shown, set `isLocked = true` in the `onPause()` method. To make sure, that your don't lock your app, when returning from your own activities, start them via `startActivityForResult()` and unlock it in `onActivityResult`.

You can now check in `onResume()` wether your app is locked and redirect the user to your login screen.