# Android : Login every time user opens the app and stay in the same activity like before

Tags: android

I am working on an android app which would require the user to login every time he opens the app. This would include the cases below

1. When he kills the app and opens it.
2. When he minimises the app and opens it.
3. Switches to other apps.

I wan't to resume the same activity from where he paused it.

From an architecture point of view, Is it better to handle these cases on client code? (like handle every onResume(), onPause() call) or do it in the middleware(Create an authentication token for the first time and use it for later calls).

I found some posts for handling it on client(android). But, I couldn't find the scenario where the app logs in every time and starts from the same activity.

Relevant posts : [Require login every time user returns to Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008019/require-login-every-time-user-returns-to-android-application) In this case, I can't resume the same activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trick for you:

1) In application since api 14 is a very useful callback ...

```
class MyApplication extends Application{
private int frameCount = 0;
private boolean fromBackground=false;

public boolean inBackground() 
{ 
    return frameCount==0;
}


public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {


        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
            frameCount--;
            if (frameCount == 0) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

            fromBackground = frameCount == 0;
            if(!(activity instanceof LoginActivity)){
                if (fromBackground) {
                    // call for login activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity,LoginActivity.class);
                    activity.startActivity(i);
                }else{
                    //get shared preferences, save there  activity.class.getCanonicalName()
                }
            }
            frameCount++;
        }
        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {}
        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {}
        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {}
        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {}
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}
    });

}
```

The activity lifecycle if you start one activity from another is called in this sequence - 1) newActivity.start. 2) oldActivity.stop
so you will have frameCount >0 untill you go to background...

2) Get class name for your activity in LoginActivity, and start it if successfuly logged in, like this:

```
if(getApplication().fromBackground()){// Login activity is the first, app was destroyed
    Class clazz = Class.forName(preferences.getName)...
    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, clazz);
    startActivity(i);
}else{ // login was called from another activity
    finish();
}
```

Error and exceptions handling was omitted.

Comment: I am gonna try this out. Thanks for the input raiv.

Comment: It doesn't work when user opens the second activity from the first one (password must not be shown).